# What prompts Aranea to join my party?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

I am at the end of chapter 8, doing a good amount of side content before finishing the story. I am running towards a quest location and some daemons want to pick a fight with something that isn't their own size.

After a few seconds into the battle, Aranea shows up out of the blue, joins my party, and helps me fight the daemons. After the fight, Noctis thanks her and she leaves.

What prompts Aranea to randomly join my party for the fight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aranea Highwind's appearance in battles after Chapter 7 isn't triggered by any specific conditions.

[Fandom](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Aranea_Highwind) states:

> After the party's first encounter with her in Chapter 7, there is a
>   rare chance Aranea will temporarily join them during battles on the
>   open world. Her drop ship will appear near the battle and she'll jump
>   into the fray, serving as a guest party member for the duration of
>   combat. Once the battle is over, she says some parting words and jumps
>   into the air, vanishing from the scene.

There is a [glitch](http://www.idigitaltimes.com/final-fantasy-15-permanent-aranea-glitch-adds-her-party-breaks-fishing-575121) that remains in v.1.03 where you can force her into your party, at the cost of an ability to fish.

Comment: I personally have only seen her join fights against demons, and her comment after the fight mentioned demons as well, so I don't think this source is accurate (unless someone's seen her join a fight during the day?)

Comment: Well, she can be forced in party, which doesn't limit her to night or demons, and there's an implication that she dropped in the day time here: https://www.reddit.com/r/FinalFantasy/comments/5isjyh/ffxv_soaranea_joined_the_party_post_game_all_of_a/